# Set permision to create nodes of certain content type programatically

Tags: nodes, users

I have created a content type. Now I need to set the permision to create a node of this content type programatically (the path node/add/this-content-type must not be accessible). How can I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hook_node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7), where you can set permissions to concrete node type by your module. Here is the example:

```
function MODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  //if it is your content type and operation
  if ($type == 'CONTENT_TYPE' && $op == 'create') {
    //specify your logic - allow or deny access to certail roles, users, etc...

    //if you would like to allow access, you have to return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW
    //if you would like to deny access, you have to return NODE_ACCESS_DENY
  }
  //in all other cases, return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE, which means, your module does not modify access in this case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant implement hook node_access in a custom module and deny access to node add page to the node/add specific path. Here you have a sample:

```
  /**
    * Implements hook_node_access().
    */
  function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'create': 
        $path = current_path();
        if ($path == 'node/add/your-content-type') {
          return NODE_ACCESS_DENY
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the permission in the admin list of permissions? Simply don't give any role the ability to add/edit/delete that type of content. They won't see any link(s) to add it.

Comment: I need to set the condition programatically because It's a bit complicated condition.

Comment: With proper permissions to who can and cannot create content of certain types, the links won't be on the node/add screen and they won't have access to node/add/(type) if not permitted, which is as much as the original post described as the issue. If more functionality is desired, there are access modules.